# how to autoscale the spring batch application in openshift?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, openshift, spring-batch

I have  a spring batch application which will trigger the job to  transfer bulk data from one database to another database through API call.All jobs are configured to work in parallel processing(Master/slave step)partition and deployed this application in openshift. Need to autoscale the application based on the load during the job execution.Even though i have used the openshift autoscale feature still i couldn't find the efficiency in performance of the job. PODs are simply creating but only one POD is getting utilized.How to fix this issue?How to split jobs among PODS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a remote partitioning setup, the master step sends `StepExecutionRequest`s to a configurable queue (let's call it `requests`). Worker steps are listeners on this queue. The master step can be configured to either:

- Aggregate replies from workers on a configurable queue (let's call it `replies`)
- Poll the job repository to check the status of workers

With this in mind, autoscaling such a setup depends on how you define your PODs. For example, if you run one or multiple workers in the same POD, you can autoscale this deployment as the size of the `requests` queue grows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your suggestion.i have couple questions.Does this mean that i have to rewrite the application code for autoscaling to work?the above suggestion is like vertical scaling of batch.

Comment: No you don't need to rewrite your app. You can use Spring profiles for master/workers and use the same app in a different profile. You can find an example here: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/blob/master/partitioned-demo/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/partitiondemo/configuration/BatchConfiguration.java#L108. As per scaling, that's horizontal scaling, you can add as much worker nodes as you want/can.